# How to get maximum brightness from an HDR10 monitor?

Tags: display, images, hdr

Suppose an HDR10 monitor can have a maximum brightness of 1000 nits. How can this maximum brightness be activated and observed in images? Do white colors in all 8-bit PNG images ( pixels with RGB(255,255,255) ) are shown with that brightness automatically? What about white pixels in 16-bit PNG images? Are special image formats supporting HDR10 required?

Comment: You need to be using an hdr profile. The gamut needs to be designed to stretch to the 'new improved' brightness levels. Trying to do this from a normal photo will not work, there's nothing in the captured data that stretches that far. tbh, I don't have much experience in this yet, so far all I see are hopelessly artificial-looking images & it's just not ready for pro use yet. Most people have difficulty understanding & making sRGB look good. 9/10 consumer displays are unclibrated, making this worse.. hdr is such a vague definition that all it results in is much more chance of it looking bad.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks for your comment. I'm not sure if the usage of the term 'gamut' is correct here. According to Wikipedia, "While HDR displays typically have WCGs (wide color gamuts) and displays with WCGs are usually capable of HDR, one does not imply the other; there are SDR displays with WCGs. Some HDR standards specify WCG as a prerequisite of compliance." As far as I have understood, RGB(a, b, c) has the same 'color' as RGB(a x k, b x k, c x k) in a gamut, though the latter has higher luminosity.

Comment: The definition of gamut is; the complete range or scope of something. In display terms, the range from darkest to lightest. If you take an sRGB gamut of 0-255 & try to apply it to hdr, all you get is that the colour stretches to fit, and as a consequence, looks terrible. You can see this easily enough between Adobe98 & sRGB  [without needing the added 10-bit complication] if you use a bad browser, Chrome, Firefox etc both of which are totally hopeless at colour profiling, at default settings. I used to have a great web link explaining this, struggling to find it right now...

Comment: @Tetsujin, It seems to me that you are confusing color gamut with color-depth. Gamut defines the boundaries of the available colors. A monitor covering DCI-P3 gamut can show colors that an sRGB compatible monitor can't, no matter what the color-depth of the latter is. Color-depth determines the number of colors picked from the gamut.

Comment: Ermm… no. It doesn't matter technically how many bits you have, 0 is black & bit-depth -1 is white. The rest is how many sub-divisions between the two. As a Photographer I still work in Adobe 98 & export to sRGB, because most of the world still struggles with making that look anywhere near right. Every so often we get one of these 'how do I stretch sRGB to P3/ProRes or this hideous no-standard 'HDR'?' Or 'How do i get more nits?' The answer really is invariably the same. You don't. It just doesn't work that way. That aside, HDR isn't really a standard, it's consumer/advertising speak.

Answer (score 0):

HDR content contains additional metadata, the exact form varies based on the type of content (images are different than video, Dolby Vision is different than HDR10). Without the HDR metadata, the content will be displayed on the SDR brightness curve, regardless of the stored pixel color values or the bit depth of the image.

SDR and HDR content are not interoperable. While it is intuitive that viewing HDR content in SDR would result in an inaccurate representation, the inverse is also true. Content from either must be remapped (i.e. tonemapping) onto an PQ Curve to achieve reasonable quality.

HDR metadata can be embedded into a variety of image file formats. While PNG is capable of storing the appropriate additional profile information, 16-bit PNG is more commonly used to store additional color complexity rather than what you might expect for HDR brightness. The JXR format is more commonly used to capture and display HDR images that can achieve peak HDR brightness.

Answer (score -1):

*I am no expert, but would still say:*

The display "nits" matters more for being able to see display content in a bright room (sunlit!), than affecting individual pixels in an image.

You might be better off hunting for a pleasant display and seeing all color tones and grey levels.
*(The ultimate, nitpicking level of this is using a color calibration device on your display[1]; not necessarily gaining much else than some level of confidence that you actually see images as they should be")*

Images of lower color depth is likely to be mapped into the larger gamut of the display, i.e. not using the full potential of 10-bits.

The effect of 8-bit color on a larger gamut device can be seen simulated here:
https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/bit-depth.htm

*As o matter of fact; check out all the tutorials there, make sure you understand them, and you will have the basis for much of digital images, editing and all around it.*

[1] Based on experience with a couple of these; Calibrite ColorChecker is good, others might not be at the same level (the experience is from older versions than available now).